# Example of discontinuous conditional mean

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions

I'm looking for an example of distribution of $(X,Y)$ with density $f_{XY}$ such that $\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]$ is not continuous, but the marginal density $f_Y = \int f_{XY}$ is continuous.

In [Transference of properties from marginals to joint density functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311904/transference-of-properties-from-marginals-to-joint-density-functions?rq=1), there is a very nice example, when $f_{XY}(x,y)=1\{|x|+|y|\leq 1\}/2$ is discontinuous on $[-1,1]^2$, while $f_Y(y)=(1-|y|)$ is continuous. But in that example the conditional mean $$\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]=\frac{1}{2(1-|x|)}\int_{-(1-|x|)}^{1-|x|}ydy=0 $$ is continuous.

Is there a good counterexample (or a way to show that it does not exist)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y\sim U(-1,1)$ and $X\mid Y=y\sim N(1\{y>0\}, 1)$. Then

$$
\mathsf{E}[X\mid Y=y]=1\{y>0\},
$$
$$
f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2}\phi(x)+\frac{1}{2}\phi(x-1), \quad\text{and}\quad f_Y(y)=1/2.
$$